# purchasing a car with a trial period

Tags: car, california, rent, title

A stranger is selling their car for $5000 and I like it for that price.

But, instead of a straight purchase, I want to arrange a deal in which
I pay $5000 in full now (without any loans) but can return the car within
the first 3 months and receive a partial refund of $4000.  I do not
want to register the car in my name until the end of those 3 months.

Roughly, I imagine we sign a contract in which a refund is promised
by the stranger and eventual registration is promised by me (if I have
not returned the car within the 3 months).  Insurance gets a little
complicated (and a little more expensive than a normal purchase) since
the government probably requires that we both have some coverage for
those 3 months.

How should we proceed?  Is there any way to avoid the double-insurance
penalty mentioned above?  In reality, only I will be driving it so
the insurer's risk is the same as if I had purchased it outright, so I
am hoping to eliminate this "penalty".

Assume that this all happens in California and the stranger is happy
with the plan, but simply wants it all to be legal.  I am also curious
to know if this deal is easier in a different US state.

Comment: I believe you will find that what you propose, specifically keeping the car in the current owner's name, is illegal in California.  Even with a lease you must register the car in using your name.  I'm also not sure why anyone in their right mind would do this.  They are taking considerable risk for not all that much in reward.

Comment: @jwh20 On your second point, I disagree.  If the stranger has confidence in his car being good, he can include this like a "guarantee" to sell for a higher price.  Anyway, if the risk is perceived as too high, just replace 4000 with 3000 in my question...there must be some balance point where these deals would be worth it to both parties.  It could improve efficiency of used car sales if the legal system allowed it.

Answer (score 1):

You want a rental and an option to buy.  You can make use of new businesses that facilitate person to person car rentals to separate these and help your seller who is unlikely to set up the contract language by themselves for one transaction; as well as resolve the insurance question with an established business process.

1. Ask your seller to list the car on one of the personal carsharing sites (I don't intend to recommend any specific service but by example I did just find one current  [market-rate Los Angeles](https://turo.com/us/en/car-rental/united-states/glendale-ca/dodge/avenger/724637?searchId=Y_-QxwmZ) listing $1575 for 3 months so this is entirely in the realm of the feasible for CA).  Work together to have the first reservation as soon as it is set up.  Whatever fees the service takes is the grease to make this work.  Whether you ultimately pay it via higher total offer, or them would be a similar decision to the seller as if you made a lower counteroffer on the asking price.
2. Separately negotiate an option to buy the car for the remainder of your total offer.